debug a core generated when running with strace
I ran my program with strace (strace /my/app) and it crashed, dumping a core file. When I open the core in gdb, the executable being "debugged" is strace, not my app.
Can I load symbols for my app and debug it from this core? How?


When I open the core in gdb, the executable being "debugged" is strace, not my app.

That's because strace crashed, not your app.

Can I load symbols for my app and debug it from this core? How?

You can use add-symbol-file /path/to/your/binary load-address to add the symbols, but this will achieve nothing (because that would be barking up the wrong tree).

My app crashed. But I found that there were actually 2 core files - one for strace and one for my app. So problem solved
